# How to use JQM theme and jQueryMobile plugin with Drupal?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I'm developing a mobile web site with Drupal 7 and i want to use jQuery mobile. I've found many plugins, but just one available with drupal 7 (jQuery Mobile module). I have also a jQuery mobile theme (jQM Theme). My problem is that doesn't work (there is just html, no css and jquery mobile displayed).
Is there someone who used this plugin and theme ? Or could you give me an efficient way to create a mobile web site with Drupal 7 ?

Thanks,
Gen

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you've read the readme properly. The module requires that certain files be patched and you have the libraries in the correct place.

I have had jQuery Mobile theme working but found that it was far from usable so built my own simplified theme.

Comment: Would love to see your theme in a sandbox :-)